# axios Can't POST nor Http, not Https from https website to CRM

Tags: http, post, https, axios, xmlhttprequest

```
axios.defaults.headers.post["Content-Type"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    
    
    axios
    .post('http://autoclik.ru/cetch', new URLSearchParams(p).toString())
```

> Error when sending request: oi {message: 'Network Error', name:
> 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request:
> XMLHttpRequest, …}code: "ERR_NETWORK"config: {transitional: {…},
> adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse:
> Array(1), timeout: 0, …}message: "Network Error"name:
> "AxiosError"request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null,
> readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload:
> XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}stack: "AxiosError: Network Error\n    at
> s.onerror
> (https://-weburl-/static/js/main.db22fcbd.js:2:535680)"[[Prototype]]:
> Error (anonymous) @ App.js:107

Strange thing that i can successfully send from localhost or from another domain on http.
But when i switch website to https it stops sending to CRM (CRM url is without https)